# ios5, ABPersonViewController - notify when person's record is updated?

Tags: ios, ios5, abpersonviewcontroller

I have a UITableViewCell that displays person's name from Address Book. When that cell is selected, the person's info is displayed using ABPersonViewController (where editing is ON).

What I want to do is if the person's first name or last name is edited then update that information in the main UITableView.

Is there any Notification or delegate which I can use to convey that information has been updated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on this so I just `reloaded my table`.

It would be great if someone can suggest any better solution like through delegate or something.